# How to split javascript string into a max of 2 parts?

Tags: javascript, string, coffeescript

I have strings like this

```
FOO hello world
BAR something else
BISCUIT is tasty
CAKE is tasty too
```

The goal is to split string **once** after the first word.  So far I'm using this

```coffeescript
# coffeescript
raw = 'FOO hello world'
parts = raw.split /\s/
[command, params] = [parts.shift(), parts.join(' ')]
command #=> FOO
params #=> hello world
```

**I don't like this for two reasons:**

1. It seems inefficient
2. I'm rejoining the string with a `' '` character. The real string parameters can be split by either a `' '` or a `\t` and I'd like to leave the originals intact.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out:

```
[ command, params ] = /^([^\s]+)\s(.*)$/.exec('FOO hello world').slice(1);
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as accepted, but please adapt it to use `.slice(1)` as @ualinker has in order to dispose of the throwaway var.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `indexOf` to find the space (for `\t` - handle it separately and choose the smaller of the two indexes) and then `slice` there:

```
var command;
var params = '';
var space = raw.indexOf(" ");
if(space == -1) {
    command = e.data;
} else {
    command = raw.slice(0, space);
    params = raw.slice(space + 1);
}
```

Also, it's a lot quicker, as it doesn't uses regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Variant of @NathanWall's answer without unnecessary variable:

```
 [command, params] = /([^\s]+)\s(.+)/.exec('FOO hello world').slice(1)
```

Comment: Oh, that's what you were talking about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple code :

```
var t = "FOO hello world";
var part1 = t.match(/(\w+\s)/)[0];
var part2 = t.replace(part1,"");
```

part1 will contain "FOO " and part2 "hello world"

Comment: This is incredibly dangerous. If the word `FOO` appears anywhere else in the params, it will also be removed.

Comment: No, with "FOO hello FOO world" it will return "FOO " and "hello FOO world", it won't replace all FOO but only the first one

Comment: I just tested it in chrome's console. Solisoft is right: `"abac".replace("a", "*")` gives you `"*bac"` (I was absolutely sure it would give `"*b*c"`!). You have to use a regex with replace in order to replace all matches.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
let raw = "FOO hello world"

raw.split(" ")
    .filter((part, index) => index !== 0)
    .join(" ")
```

Baically, take the word, split it by the space (or whatever), then filter the first one away, then join it back up.

I find this more intuitive than doing the slicing above.

Answer (score -2):

Another option is:

```
# coffeescript
raw = 'FOO hello world'
[command, params] = raw.split(/\s/, 2)
command #=> FOO
params #=> hello world
```

Which I thin't looks more *semantic* than your original code.

Comment: thanks for trying to help here. I also saw that `.split()` accepts 2 arguments.  Unfortunately, in your example above, it will only return `[FOO, hello]`. `world` gets chopped off :(